# Eclipse, open declaration that is defined in a library

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse if I press F3 or open declaration on a reference that is in one of my libraries, it opens a read only copy of the code.

I thought this quite useful at first as reminds me that it's library code and changes could affect more projects. But I find it a pain to have to go and manually find the .java file if I do want to edit.

Can I either: a) make it always open the related .java file, or b) once readonly copy is open, quickly get to the editable .java file.

Comment: You can attach the source to any library.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have the dependent library open as a Java project within Eclipse, you can add the project to the build path. ( Right click on project -> properties -> java build path -> Projects -> Add).

Under the *Order and Export* section, make sure the project is above the library.

After doing this when you press F3, the .java file will open.

Comment: correct the answer to: `make sure the library is above the Android Dependencies.`

Comment: Thanx @Can't Tell and @breceivemail. One must both do `make sure the project is above the library` and `make sure the library is above the Android Dependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach correct source when you ctrl+click or press F3 to any class which is in the library. Just click on attach source -> external folder -> attach the src folder of the library you are using. Eclipse will itself find out the correct .java file.

I had the same issue with Action interface in struts 2.0. So i attached the src folder inside my struts directory and bobs your uncle.